$\mathbb{k}$-linear tensor functor
In the context of an abelian tensor category $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$, with $\mathbb{k} = \text{End}(\mathbf{1})$, with $\mathbf{1}$ the identity object, what does it mean to say that a functor $F:\mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Vect}_{\mathbb{k}}$ is $\mathbb{k}$-linear?
I am thinking in particular of in the context of proposition 1.20 in Tannakian Categories.

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/linear+functor

First, we say that a category is $k$-linear if its homsets are $k$-vector spaces and composition is bilinear. This is a special case of the notion of an enriched category; typical examples include the category of modules over a $k$-algebra, or representations of a group over $k$.
Next, if $A, B$ are two $k$-linear categories, a functor $F : A \to B$ is $k$-linear if the induced maps on homsets is $k$-linear. Typical examples include tensor product and hom of modules. In the context of Proposition 1.20, an important class of examples is the forgetful functor from modules or representations of a group to $\text{Vect}$; $F$ is supposed to generalize this example (for groups in particular).
It is a not entirely obvious fact that if $A, B$ have finite direct sums then a $k$-linear functor automatically preserves them. Also, a monoidal abelian category is automatically $\text{End}(1)$-linear, because $\text{End}(1)$ naturally acts on every object and on every homset.
To help clarify the concept, here are two examples of functors which are not $k$-linear, for different reasons.

The functor $V \mapsto \Lambda^n(V)$ given by taking the $n^{th}$ exterior power is a functor $\text{Vect} \to \text{Vect}$ which is not $k$-linear (for $n \ge 2$) because the map it induces on homsets is not additive (however, it is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $n$).
The category $\text{Vect}_{\mathbb{C}}$ of complex vector spaces has an automorphism $V \mapsto \overline{V}$ sending a vector space $V$ to the conjugate vector space; formally it inserts a complex conjugate into scalar multiplication. This functor is $\mathbb{R}$-linear but not $\mathbb{C}$-linear.


Thanks as always for a very generous answer =).
I would be very interested on your take on why $\mathbf{1} \simeq U \oplus U^{\perp}$ in prop 1.17 in Tannakian Categories. I can follow everything up to that very last statement.

@Ben123: at a glance I'm not sure. This should really be a separate question.
